# mysql search - return id only if it's present in all of the conditions

Tags: mysql, search

I have a yable for **members** and a table for the **services** that each member provides:

```
MemberID | ServiceID
--------------
1        | 2
1        | 3
2        | 1
2        | 3
```

So a member can provide any number of services. 
I have a search form which lets the user check some or all of the services. I want to be able to select all of the members that provides ALL of the services that the user selected (and not just some of them). I used `WHERE ... IN..`, but it returns all of the members that provides at least one of the selected services. 
I now have a query similar to:

```
SELECT members.id
FROM 
members
LEFT JOIN services ON (members.id=services.memberID)
WHERE members.id IN (....)
```

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I used Vinay Pai solution and it worked like a charm. Since Malvolio solution it's similar, I guess it would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT memberID
FROM services
WHERE ServiceID IN (...)
GROUP BY memberID
HAVING COUNT(*) = x;
```

where (...) is a list of all the selected servicesIDs, and x is the number of items in (...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `LEFT` join and the fact you are checking `members.id` in the where clause ("select all of the members that provides ALL of the services that the user selected", so you should be checking on servicesID):

```
SELECT members.id
FROM 
members
JOIN services ON (members.id=services.memberID)
WHERE servicesID IN (....)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually use a variation of this question when I do interviews (thanks for coming in, Mr Ant, we will let you know if we decide to move forward).  If the number of services is small:

```
select s1.member_id from services s1, services s2, services s3
where s1.member_id = s2.member_id and s2.member_id = s3.member_id
and s1.service_id = 1 and s2.service_id = 2 and s3.service_id = 3
```

If the number of services is unreasonably high, but member_id,service_id is unique

```
select member_id from services group by member_id having count(*) = 100;
```

(if there are 100 services).  Worse case scenario (no uniqueness guarantee):

```
select member_id from services group by member_id having count(distinct service_id) = 100;
```

Which is slow, but works.

Comment: that's an interview question - eeek loool

Comment: For anyone who claimed to be good at SQL, yes, it certainly was.  If you can't do aggregation and aliasing, you can't play with my toys.